# Record and encode Flash video?

Tags: html, flash, video, streaming

**Is it possible to record video through Flash's "Webcam" facility and receive encoded video on server side** without any further processing (i.e. just saving the stream to a file)? Or is server side software always needed to encode the input?

If server side software is necessary, are there free / Open Source solutions available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you have to use server side software to capture and distribute. There are open source solutions: http://osflash.org/red5. I tried using this and it was too much of a hassle to install, though, so I just used Flash Media Server http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/ hosted by another company.