# Real-time audio record/playback from a Ruby web app

Tags: ruby, html, audio-recording

I am wondering if anyone has success with audio record (from microphone on the users browser) and playback from a web based app (Ruby/RoR)?

What I have found so far - I could write a flex/flash app which will record the audio and then have a server side like Red5 or so to receive and convert. This sounds more involved and I also saw different types of hosting issues etc people are having - so I am thinking there may be better/easier solutions out there!! I looked at html5/web-kit too but seems to only works on chrome and is limited to text fields etc.

In my app, i want to record users voice, save it on a aws/s3 as mp3 or similar file format and play it back to user within the app based on users input/choice. While flash based solution is workable for now, non-flash based solution will be preferred as it will support more devices (you know devices I am referring)..

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065797/how-to-record-voice-files-using-php-flash

Answer (score 1):

The only options for web based record are Flash, Silverlight or Java. None of these will work on an iPhone or iPad - You will need a native app for that.

You don't need to use Red5 for Flash recording - you can record direct to memory, optionally encode (or zip), and then upload the the data. You might be better doing mp3 encoding server-side using ffmpeg or SoX before moving the file to s3.

Comment: The downside of recording direct to memory in Flash is that the APIs for that don't support compression, so you're going to be sending uncompressed wavs back to your server.

Comment: @warhammerkid there are options - zip is easy enough and there are as3 / alchemy implemenations of flac, mp3, etc

Comment: Thank you both for your answers and comments - helpful. Have you seen any opensource even experimental code in flex - might save me time instead of writing from scratch? I searched, found one that sells license to his flash binaries - I am not confortable depending on binary from little known sources, so looking for better options. I also saw preliminarily a Tropo (a phone app that might be able to kludged up to a webapp) has some audio apis that uses their service for recording.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way using HTML5 and a server. Just record a video.
Convert the video to audio, then use the audio as you wish.

This implementation takes audio from a video and runs 
ffmpeg to extract the audio:

http://goo.gl/A0bya

This is in PHP, but it should not be too 
hard to create a Ruby version. Easy peasy.