# Is it possible to capture video/audio stream from web-cam in browser via js / HTML5/ ... with out Software

Tags: video-streaming, conference, webinar

Is it possible to do this reliably through a browser whitout using Flash, silverlight, ActiviX, Java, any software.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do this reliably through a browser whitout using Flash, silverlight, ActiviX, Java, any software.

Nope. If you want to work in a browser, you will need at least Flash to do this, and for Video capturing you will definitely need something corresponding on server side.

See

- [How does one record audio from a Javascript based webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010/how-does-one-record-audio-from-a-javascript-based-webapp) (Audio related but the product is the same)
- [Record and encode Flash video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940789/record-and-encode-flash-video)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is bringing us the getUserMedia method, which will allow obtaining of browser's webcam/audio directly from JavaScript.

See [this link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)!